# Realistic 3D Lighting in Unity

Tags: unity, 3d, lighting

The game I am working on is in 3D, and I need to create a realistic looking recessed ceiling light, preferably without any 3rd party plugins or tools, as I am on a school computer.

What is the best way to go about doing this in Unity?

I am using a point light at the moment, but they are hard on memory, and I would like this game to run smoothly on mobile devices.

Comment: You mean like a simple pot light? The built-in spotlight type should handle this case quite well. Can you give more details on what you've tried so far and what aspects you're not satisfied with / what you're trying to improve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever heard this sentence "Camera, Light, Action"?. Off course you know about it but what does it mean? It means that Light is another big, wide and great area of gaming and it is not a small topic. So basically you have to learn the lighting your self no one can ever define it to you in this single post. You can ask speicfic issue about lighting here but your rest of the part question require an answer that you want to run your mobile game smoothly. So you can consider [bakingLightmaps](https://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/Manual/Lightmapping.html) in unity in perspective of Lights.

For further reading

1. [lightmapping-in-unity-5](http://sassybot.com/blog/lightmapping-in-unity-5/)
2. [Unity-5-lighting-and-rendering](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/unity-5-lighting-and-rendering)
3. [Practical Guide to Optimization for Mobiles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileOptimizationPracticalGuide.html)
4. [What is baking lights in Unity3d](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/402504/what-is-baking-lights-in-unity3d-and-what-are-the.html)